# Why are rainy scenes in Thelma & Louise sunny?

Tags: plot-explanation, thelma-and-louise

Why do rainy scenes in [Thelma & Louise](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103074/) movie happen in sunny weather? I know sometimes when it rains it's possible to see the sun in sky, but this happens in several scenes even in different cities. Is it a gaffe or has it been deliberately made like that?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe there's a small dark rainy cloud over them :).

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find much, but what I could find leads me to believe that it was just Mother Nature's unwillingness to cooperate. It happens sometimes, as I'm sure you've seen in other films. It's possible it could have some deeper meaning, but I didn't see any production notes anywhere alluding to it. The two primary shooting locations are listed as Bakersfield, CA and Moab, UT, so it's likely it was just unlucky weather.

Answer (score 0):

In movies, they often create the rain themselves. They may have kept it in daylight so that you could clearly see the actors and what was happening in the scenes. If they had filmed it at night, it might have been difficult to see what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

I found another answer in the Earth Science community.

Apparently, a Sunshower is created when the wind blows the rain into an area where there are no clouds. It can also occur if there is a single rain cloud overhead, but it does not block out the Sun. Sun showers are also likely to create rainbows.

https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/9696

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/92160)

Comment: I will edit the answer and follow your suggestions.